# synchronized methods in Android Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, synchronization, thread-safety

I have two activities.  In activity 1 I write a value to a SQLite database by entering that value into an EditText field.  Once I press the submit button, the data is written and I am moved along to another activity - activity 2.  Activity2 also does the same thing in that I can write new data and persist it to the database with a button click.  So, my question is: do I need to synchronize the method (which is on a separate thread from the UI) in activity 1, as well as the method in activity 2 in order to prevent thread safety issues in the database?  Keep in mind that both methods access the same database but from different activities.  Technically, activity 1 should be complete with onStop having been called and the new activity (activity 2), now being visible.  Is it even possible for these two activities and their corresponding threads accessing the database (via different methods) to have any kind of concurrency problems given the Android activity life cycle?

Thanks very much,
Matt

Answer (score 1):

Check this method

```
SQLiteDatabase.setLockingEnabled(boolean lockingEnabled)
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I was not aware of this method.  However, the question still remains - do I need it given the life cycle of Android Activities?

Comment: [The method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#setLockingEnabled(boolean)) is deprecated

Comment: Did you mention since which version is depricated?

Answer (score 0):

How is your background thread created? A background thread will continue to run even after an activity has been stopped.

If data in activity 2 will not be persisted until the user has entered some data, then it seems like a lock would be unnecessary given the fact that the data from activity 1 should persist in a matter of milliseconds.

However, if you're preparing for the worst case scenario, I don't see how a database lock would hurt anything (as @Pepi suggested). The only way I can see this being a problem is if work being done in your background thread (activity 1) is hanging on something before it can commit the data. If activity 2 starts it's own background worker to commit data, then you could potentially have a race between these two background threads.

Comment: This was my thought exactly, and the worse case scenario seemed to be the only caveat.  Depending on the activity, I am creating threads either with a handler, or with a simple inner class that extends Thread.  It just depends.  So I guess that will just leave them synchronized, even though it appears that in theory it should not be necessary 99.99% of the time - if ever.  Also, these processes are pretty short in duration - nothing major, so it should be okay.  Thanks.

Comment: @javamatt You should mark one of our answers as "correct" so that this question is categorized as answered.